# Why the obtained rxPower () is always Zero, every where?

Tags: omnet++, inet

```
void Ieee80211AgentSTA::dumpAPList(Ieee80211Prim_ScanConfirm *resp)
{
EV << "Received AP list:\n";
for (int i = 0; i < (int)resp->getBssListArraySize(); i++) {
    Ieee80211Prim_BSSDescription& bssDesc = resp->getBssList(i);
    EV << "    " << i << ". "
       << " address=" << bssDesc.getBSSID()
       << " channel=" << bssDesc.getChannelNumber()
       << " SSID=" << bssDesc.getSSID()
       << " beaconIntvl=" << bssDesc.getBeaconInterval()
       << " rxPower=" << bssDesc.getRxPower()
       << endl;
    // later: supportedRates
}
}
```

I executed the existing `mobileIPv6` example, noticed that everywhere the returned value of `rxpower` is equal to zero.

I changed the MN's position near and far from the access point but nothing change about the `rxpower`

Another thing I want to know is: is the `rxpower` equal to `RSSI` (received signal strength indicator)? or can I get `RSSI` from `rxPower`?

---

Events of the simulation log:

> ** Event #256  t=0.165239371312  mIPv6Network.MN[0].wlan[0].agent (Ieee80211AgentSTA, id=127), on selfmsg `startUp' (cMessage, id=28)
>   Starting up Sending ScanRequest primitive to mgmt
>   ** Event #1372  t=0.815239371312  mIPv6Network.MN[0].wlan[0].agent (Ieee80211AgentSTA, id=127), on`
>   inet::ieee80211::Ieee80211Prim_ScanConfirm' (cMessage, id=1680)
>   Processing confirmation from mgmt:
>   inet::ieee80211::Ieee80211Prim_ScanConfirm DEBUG: current position =
>   (180.408, 100, 0) Received AP list:
>       0.  address=10-AA-00-00-00-01 channel=1 SSID=HOME beaconIntvl=0.1 ***rxPower=0*** Chosen AP address=10-AA-00-00-00-01 from list, starting authentication Sending AuthenticateRequest primitive to mgmt
>   ** Event #1460  t=0.81767038585  mIPv6Network.MN[0].wlan[0].agent (Ieee80211AgentSTA, id=127), on
>   `inet::ieee80211::Ieee80211Prim_AuthenticateConfirm' (cMessage,
>   id=1823) Processing confirmation from mgmt:
>   inet::ieee80211::Ieee80211Prim_AuthenticateConfirm Authentication
>   successful, let's try to associate Sending AssociateRequest primitive
>   to mgmt
>   ** Event #1513  t=0.81913139312  mIPv6Network.MN[0].wlan[0].agent (Ieee80211AgentSTA, id=127), on`
>   inet::ieee80211::Ieee80211Prim_AssociateConfirm' (cMessage, id=1908)
>   Processing confirmation from mgmt:
>   inet::ieee80211::Ieee80211Prim_AssociateConfirm Association successful

Comment: please use proper formatting and spelling in your question. it is more likely that a high quality question will generate proper responses. you are also missing the image you intended to attach...

Comment: thanks for the correction and the editing, as I'm new user it takes time to get better..  for the image the server didn't allow me to publish as I'm new user...then I forgot to erase the line that talk about image, thus I coped the simulation event log... thanks any way..

Comment: no problem it's OK. I can see you are a new user. just wanted to note for future reference. I removed the unnecessary line bthw...

Comment: I'm not familiar with this use case, but maybe you have some parameter in `omnetpp.ini` which turns off `txPower`/`rxPower`